# Chapter-specific headers using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to use the fancyhdr package to format the headers for my dissertation, and I'm running into some problems.

For the introduction, I would like the even pages to have the page number and the word *Introduction* on the left-hand side, and for the odd pages, I would like to have the same thing (but the order transposed) on the right-hand side.

However, the remaining chapters have sections, so I would like to format them differently.  I want the page number followed by *Chapter name* on the left-hand side of every even page, and the *Section name* followed by the page number on the right-hand side of every odd page.

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
...
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\qquad Introduction}
\fancyhead[RO]{Introduction\qquad\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{fancy}
...
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\qquad\thechapter .~\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thesection~\rightmark\qquad\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chapter{Background}
\pagestyle{fancy}
...
```

However, the last page of the Introduction has a header that corresponds to what the header for the next chapter should be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...thanks!!

Comment: Can't test right now, but does a `\cleardoublepage` before the redefinition help?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it does!  However, it introduces a new problem: it adds an additional (blank) page to my introduction...with the correct header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style is applied to the current page. So you need to clear the page first. This is done by `\clearpage` (end current page) or `\cleardoublepage`(clear current page and optionally add a blank page so that the next page with content is an odd page), depending on whether your chapters can start on any page or always start on an odd page.